# Authentication problem while using the Google Cloud Translation API in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts, google-translation-api

I've tried using the google translation API with the help of the official document, but I encountered a problem using version 3 that supports a glossary function. The code below returns the following error where I used my personal projectId inside *'[PROJECT_ID]'*.

Some of the answers I found suggested using the *gcloud auth application-default login* command with json file but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Is there an alternative solution for authentication other than using the gcloud command?

> Uncaught DomainException: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information in /home/user/production/test.org/vendor/google/auth/src/ApplicationDefaultCredentials.php:189 Stack trace: #0

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\TranslationServiceClient;

$translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
$content = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$targetLanguage = 'es';
$response = $translationClient->translateText(
    $content,
    $targetLanguage,
    TranslationServiceClient::locationName('[PROJECT_ID]', 'global')
);

foreach ($response->getTranslations() as $key => $translation) {
    $separator = $key === 2
        ? '!'
        : ', ';
    echo $translation->getTranslatedText() . $separator;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you It cant find your service account key file.

1. If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS isn't set, ADC uses the service account that is attached to the resource that is running your code.
2. This service account might be a default service account provided by Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, Cloud Run, or Cloud Functions. It might also be a user-managed service account that you created.
3. If ADC can't use any of the above credentials, an error occurs.

Try

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');
```

Comment: Is the service-account.json equal to API key that you download from google cloud console?

Comment: No api keys are only used to access public data.  What you want for this is a service account [How to create service account credetinals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asrCdWFrF0A)  make sure to enable google translate under library.   Or see  [docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#service_account_and_private_key)

Comment: I have spent 6 hours trying to set up GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS through terminal like Google Docs suggest with no result (shared Cpanel hosting). putenv worked.